# Finding number between [/ and ] using regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I want to find the number between `[/` and `]` (`12345` in this case).

I have written  such code:

```
float num;
string line = "A111[/12345]";
boost::regex e ("[/([0-9]{5})]");
boost::smatch match;
    if (boost::regex_search(line, match, e))
    {
        std::string s1(match[1].first, match[1].second);
        num = boost::lexical_cast<float>(s1); //convert to float
        cout << num << endl;
    }
```

However, I get this error: `The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '/([0-9]{5}>>>HERE>>>)]'.`

Comment: You need to escape [

Comment: You have to escape the outer braces like `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: yeah - sorry. A `\ ` has to be escaped in a c++ string to `\\ `. So the final string should look like `\\[/([0-9]{5})\\]`

Comment: @Vera rind No problem. yup that'll do it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double escape the `[` and `]` that special characters in regex denoting [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). The correct regex declaration will be

```
boost::regex e ("\\[/([0-9]{5})\\]");
```

This is necessary because C++ compiler also uses a backslash to escape entities like `\n`, and regex engine uses the backslash to escape special characters so that they are treated like literals. Thus, backslash gets doubled. When you need to match a literal backslash, you will have to use 4 of them (i.e. `\\\\`).

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the link. i'll use it as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following (escape `[` and `]` because they are special characters in regex meaning a character class):

```
\\[/([0-9]{5})\\]
^^            ^^
```